# Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, jackson

How do i convert  `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`  into  `org.json.JSONObject`

```
 import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
    ....
    ....
    JSONObject rawSchema = ExportUtil.getFileAndConvertToJson(environment.getProperty("export.path")+ "schema.json");  
    org.json.JSONObject rawSchema1 = rawSchema; // Exception: Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject to org.json.JSONObject
```

---

```
public static JSONObject getFileAndConvertToJson(String filePath) {
    File fileToDownload = new File(filePath);
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload)) {
        BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String inputStr;
        while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
        responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all, `ExportUtil.getFileAndConvertToJson` is returning a `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` which you are trying to assign to a `org.json.JSONObject` variable

Comment: I updated my question, how do i convert into `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` Object

Comment: can you modify the getFileAndConvertToJson method? if yes, then you should build a org.json.JSONObject object in the last line before the catch. org.json.JSONObject also has a constructor that takes a String https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String- If you can't modify getFileAndConvertToJson, and you do need an org.json.JSONObject object, then you can always build a new org.json.JSONObject passing the string representation of the org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject to its constructor (new org.json.JSONObject(rawSchema.toString()); )

Comment: I don't want to use `org.json.JSONObject` , instead i have to use `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`. Thats the requirement

Comment: then remove the line org.json.JSONObject rawSchema1 = rawSchema; and use rawSchema which is of type org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

you should use the same class JSONObject, not org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: How do i convert